# Is there really an answer for this Riley?

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is so real,
> My suffix tastes good with a tac.
> My infix is,
> My whole is too real.

Comment: I like the idea of hiding some of the -fixes in plain sight, but the execution needs some work; in particular the "whole" clue cannot just give the answer away like that.

Comment: Please do not make edits than invalidate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling the answer to this one is intended to be:

> **REALISTIC**

*My prefix is so real,*

> Here the prefix is merely **REAL**.

*My suffix tastes good with a tac.*

> A [**TIC** Tac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic_Tac) is a sweet mint.

*My infix is,*

> Here the infix is merely **IS**.

*My whole is too real.*

> If something is **REALISTIC** it is accurate or true-to-life - reflective of the *real* situation.

However, if this is correct, some feedback:

> There are ways to clue both prefix and infix without resorting to hiding-in-plain-sight answers (Real Madrid, Brazilian currency... Iceland (or many other [things that abbreviate to 'IS'](https://www.abbreviations.com/IS)), even 'LIST', etc.). These tend to be much more satisfying than merely trying to spot which words on the page directly in front of you can be assembled into a real word... Just some food for thought!

Comment: @math You're welcome. Just some tips I've learned from experience of a lot of these riddles... Keep creating, and keep trying to unlock new parts of your imagination! :)

Comment: Keep cheating on wordfinder and word hippo more like .

Answer (score 1):

You're

> the word *too*

My prefix is so real,

> $t$ denotes *time* in physics and math. Time is usually *real* (i.e. not imaginary) variable, unless in some areas of quantum mechanics.

My suffix tastes good with a tac.

> *o* with a "tac" is "taco". Tacos usually taste good.

My infix is,

> *o* means "zero", i.e. nothing.

My whole is too real.

> Well, it's *really* "too".

Comment: Very nice answer, but unfortunately not correct.